# Turning on flashlight and camera that does not support flash simultaneously in Android

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2, flashlight

I'm writing a highly specialized application for the [Kyocera E6820](http://www.kyoceramobile.com/duraforce-pro/?gclid=Cj0KEQjwg47KBRDk7LSu4LTD8eEBEiQAO4O6r5etkp8URnnNNz-rd3DZcHSmkp_YQ7JOhVppa1T20GAaAoke8P8HAQ) that requires the device's wide angle camera and the flashlight to be on simultaneously.

I'm using the [Camera2 Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html). The problem is that by default the wide angle camera doesn't support flash, so if I try to turn on the flashlight and the wide angle camera at the same time by doing the following:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

I get an error that says:

```
W/LegacyRequestMapper: mapAeAndFlashMode - Ignore flash.mode == TORCH;camera does not support it
```

I tried to get around this by turning on the flash using the regular rear facing camera (which does support flash) without opening it by doing the following:

```
manager.openCamera(wideAngleCameraID, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
manager.setTorchMode(rearFacingCameraID, true);
```

However, it didn't work, and I got this message:

```
W/System.err: android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: The system-wide limit for number of open cameras has been reached, and more camera devices cannot be opened until previous instances are closed.
```

I can get the normal rear facing camera and the flashlight to go on simultaneously, but no such luck with the wide angle.

Does anyone know a potential way around this problem? I've already looked through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202403/how-to-turn-on-flashlight-and-front-camera-at-the-same-time-in-android) but didn't find anything useful. Since this is such a specialized application it is not out of the question to do something like rooting the phone or talking directly to the device's LED drivers, but I would need to know where to start. Any direction or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone viewing, I found the answer after looking at [this forum discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/AyEMaRshntM/qlmnXptzfDMJ). For me, the brightness value was located in the

```
/sys/class/leds/led:torch_0
```

directory. After rooting the phone, I was able to manipulate the value by invoking an adb command using the process given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381828/is-it-possible-to-execute-adb-commands-through-my-android-app).